# CompareItem not called in class derived from CComboBox

Tags: mfc

I need a combobox which allows me to sort the items based on something else that alphabetical sort.

Therefore I derived a class `CCMyComboBox` from `CComboBox` and I implemented the `CompareItem` function:

```
class CCMyComboBox : public CComboBox
{
  virtual int CompareItem( LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT lpCompareItemStruct );
public:
  CCMyComboBox() ;
} ;


int CCMyComboBox ::CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT lpCompareItemStruct)
{
  return 0 ;  // stub
}

CCMyComboBox::CCMyComboBox()
{
   // stub constructor
}
```

For the moment `CompareItem` function is just a stub, but the problem is `CompareItem` never gets called; the stub constructor however gets called.

The combobox is not owner drawn. Using the CBS_SORT style or not makes no difference.

Comment: The documentation seem to impliy it's only called for a sorted, owner drawn combo box?

Comment: To add to what @imbtfab indicated, here's the MSDN on that... If you create an owner-draw combo box with the LBS_SORT style, you must override this member function to assist the framework in sorting new items added to the list box